# Flutter: remove each items saved shared preferences one by one

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreferences and want to delete saved items one by one, but I want to keep some of them. For example, if there are 4 items, then I want to delete just 2 of them.
I found how to delete all items at once by using "prefs.clear()" or "prefs.remove('events')".

If you give me any advice, I would appreciate it!
Thank you.

```
  CalendarController _controller;
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _events;
  List<dynamic> _selectedEvents;
  TextEditingController _eventController;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
    _eventController = TextEditingController();
    _events = {};
    _selectedEvents = [];
    initPrefs();
  }

  initPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _events = Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>>.from(
          decodeMap(json.decode(prefs.getString("events") ?? "{}")));
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> encodeMap(Map<DateTime, dynamic> map) {
    Map<String, dynamic> newMap = {};
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      newMap[key.toString()] = map[key];
    });
    return newMap;
  }

  Map<DateTime, dynamic> decodeMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    Map<DateTime, dynamic> newMap = {};
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      newMap[DateTime.parse(key)] = map[key];
    });
    return newMap;
  }


  
            ..._selectedEvents.map((event) => ListTile(
                  onLongPress: () {

                   ***// I want to do some action here!!!***

                  }
                  title: Text(event),
                )),
```

Comment: The whole code is here.  Thank you.
https://github.com/lohanidamodar/flutter_calendar/blob/part2/lib/main.dart

Comment: You want to delete all items one by one but you don't want to delete them all at once? Why?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I mean I want to keep some of them. 
For example, if there are 4 items, then I want to delete just 2 of them.

Comment: Then edit your question and clarify that, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to get those variables you want to keep, clear shared_preferences and write the variables again. Otherwise you gonna have to remove each variable using `preferences.remove('keyName')`.

In your code you're saving your events data as a json string. Thus, if I get it right, to remove some variables, you need to get that string, decode json, remove variables, encode the string and save it.

I would suggest you to make use of [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) instead of shared_preferences, because it gets more and more complicated to manage your data as your app grows. Shared prefs are used for keeping very simple data between app starts.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. 
This is a calendar app and if I delete items using "preferences.remove('keyName')" , I will lose all of the data on the calendar...

Comment: I understand now. I will try on making the app using sqflite!! Thank you for all of your kindness.

Comment: Be happy,  bro :-)